# foreach validation not working in my case PHP

Tags: php, arrays, validation, foreach

I am trying to validate the input with foreach function in PHP but in my case it not working.
I am trying to check the empty textbox with `variables` patterns too.
I also check other threads on this same StackOverflow and SitePoint but it was not helpful for me.
Please help me with how I do this same.

my code which I am trying to do is here [code editor](https://paiza.io/projects/ZD-jHQ_ImOAWg1EWpdHDPQ?language=php) -

```
$remark = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remark'])));
$remark = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'], ' ', $remark);

$name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));
$name = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'], ' ', $name);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($_POST[$remark])) {
        $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $value[$remark] . ' is required'];
        echo json_encode($msg);
        exit();
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",($_POST[$remark]))) {
        $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $value[$remark] . ' is not valid pattern'];
        echo json_encode($msg);
        exit();
    } else {
        $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'OK'];
        echo json_encode($msg);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be specific what error you are getting ? 

I can give you a prompt solution by looking at your code at the moment. is you can use `break` instead of `exit()` , because `exit()` halt the script, whereas `break` only break the `foreach`

Comment: no any error comes

Answer (score 0):

so far, I can see you might get number of errors here.
you have to write all the validation code inside a `isset()` function.
for example. you want to perform all of the validation when the button is clicked
in that case, you need you use something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])) {    
$remark = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remark'])));
    $remark = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'], ' ', $remark);
    
    $name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));
    $name = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'], ' ', $name);
    
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($_POST[$remark])) {
            $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $rate[$remark] . ' is required'];
            echo json_encode($msg);
            break;
        } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",($_POST[$remark]))) {
            $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $rate[$remark] . ' is not valid pattern'];
            echo json_encode($msg);
            break;
        } else {
            $msg = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'OK'];
            echo json_encode($msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and use `break` instead of `exit()` to get the message visible and readable. because `exit()` halt the script and never execute the line after whereas `break` halt only `foreach` and gives you the message you wanted to see

Comment: I am getting only this message `is required` here not show `what is required ?`

Comment: can you post image or the type of error you getting. will make more sense of it. and it is always better to post HTML too.

Comment: ok sir - I will care about this in the future Pls see the image `https://ibb.co/RBdX2j7
` , `https://ibb.co/xH3Dx9N` , `https://ibb.co/7k5dzWV`

Comment: images are not clear. can you please use online code editing tool

Comment: I mentioned what message I getting. What code I am using, and what data post though dev tooo. this is my real code sir in cropped image link